# Define var Ext in Extjs source code

Tags: javascript, extjs

I found that the global variable Ext is defined in source code like this:

```
var Ext = Ext || {};
```

I wonder if it is neccessary to do so, and, I consider it may be better if just define it like

```
var Ext = {};
```

Could someone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is - the first one defines the new object in case if it does not exist yet.

The second - always creates the new object.

Comment: I know what you mean,but the rest code following the definition add a load of methods and properties to the Ext object regardless whether Ext is defined before, so apparently it is non-sense except avoiding create a '{}'